# how to remove unused triggers from quartz tables

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm using spring with Quartz and every thing is working fine but some previously cofigured triggers also got executed because they are stored in Quartz tables.
Manually we can delete all unconfigured triggers and execute the application but that is not a good practice.
I want to remove all the triggers through a spring+quartz property or some other solution.

When I have configured 3 triggers in spring configuration file like

```
<property name="triggers">
    <list>
        <ref bean="FirstTrigger" />
        <ref bean="secondTrigger" />
        <ref bean="ThirdTrigger"/>
    </list>
</property>
```

When server started, all the triggers stored in Quartz tables with corresponding cron triggers and job details.
If i remove any of the triggers in my configuration, in above for example I removed second Trigger, but it wasn't removed from Quartz tables.
At that time DBtrigger (removed trigger) also executed.

In spring + Quartz integration, is there any property to handle this problem or do we need to do something else for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might not like this, but in a previous project we re-created all the quartz tables on each release to *solve* this issue. What GaborSch says might work, but as far as I remember, using the API doesn't delete the records from the DB, it just removes the in-memory data from the scheduler.

Comment: @Augusto I used this API even to delete triggers. It depends on the `Store` type you use, but if it's a DB store, it will delete from there.

Comment: Is there any new approach that can solve this problem? Or the DB solution should be the accepted one?

Answer (score 7):

If you store triggers in DB (suppose your triggers are cron-based), you can simply delete records like this:

```
DELETE FROM QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME='scheduler' and TRIGGER_NAME='myTrigger' and TRIGGER_GROUP='DEFAULT';
DELETE FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME='scheduler' and TRIGGER_NAME='myTrigger' and TRIGGER_GROUP='DEFAULT';
```

You may also consider looking around other Quartz DB tables to find leftovers related to your job.

Comment: In case you need to clean up the other quartz tables (this is the correct order):

                delete from qrtz_cron_triggers;
                delete from qrtz_scheduler_state;
                delete from qrtz_fired_triggers;
                delete from qrtz_locks;
                delete from qrtz_paused_trigger_grps;
                delete from qrtz_simple_triggers;
                delete from qrtz_triggers;
                delete from qrtz_job_details;

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Quartz Scheduler, Jobs, Triggers, etc. using the [Quartz API](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/quick-start).

Have a look at this [Quartz CookBook](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/cookbook/), you will find out how to list all the triggers defined, etc. Maybe you should remove the unnecessary triggers using this API.

Comment: Thank you  but in spring integration with quartz , is there any property is available to remove the unused triggers. If we dont have any solution then we need to go for Quartz api only. right?

Comment: I know, but I haven't used that. This solution may be your last hope, if nothing else helps :)

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for quick reply.   I'm using oracle quartz related DBScript. if you write any job and configured in Spring-Quartz properties file, that job class will execute based on that cron expression. so as per your comments before calling the triggers we need to remove all triggers and again reload  the triggers through Spring+Quartz api. right?

Comment: i want to know the actual concept of <isclustered> property and value is true / false.

Comment: If you remove the triggers, the jobs are not run. So, it is enough to remove the triggers only, maybe later you have to use the same job.

Comment: In `<isclustered>` mode, the instances are cooperating, only one instance will run a job at a specific time, but you cannot tell, which one (Quartz determines). The other time it mmay run on the second instance, the third time again one the first instance... Quartz does some optimisation on this, considering the instance load and which instance run it last time. I made some interesting tests: in cluster mode I switched off one node (`kill -9`), then later I restarted. The new node immediately took over the half of the load from the other server. That was impressive for me.